# How do I return to the original state of my screen after an API request?

Tags: javascript, react-native, api

My project consists of two states, the first state the user selects an image from the gallery and clicks the select button, the second state the user makes an API call by clicking another button.

My goal is to switch states by clicking on their respective buttons, currently I can go from the first state to the second state, but I cannot go from the second state to the first state.

- App.js

```
   const pickImageAsync = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setSelectedImage(result.assets[0].uri);
      setShouldShow(!shouldShow);
    } else {
      alert("You need to choose an image.");
    }
  };

   return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      {shouldShow ? (
        <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
          <Button theme="primary" label="Escolher imagem"  onPress={pickImageAsync} />
        </View>
        ) : null}

      {!shouldShow ? (
          <View style={styles.footerContainer}  >
            <PostRequest />
          </View>
        ) : null}
            
    </View>
  );
```

- PostRequest.js

```
  const [shouldShow, setShouldShow] = useState(true);

  const postExample = async () => {
    try {
        await fetch(
            'https://reqres.in/api/posts', requestOptions)
            .then(response => {
                response.json()
                    .then(data => {
                        Alert.alert("Post created at : ",
                        data.createdAt);
                        });
            })
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
  }

    return (
        <View style={styles.btn}>
        <Button onPress={() => {postExample; setShouldShow(!shouldShow)}} > Post</Button>
        </View>
    )

}
```

To do this I tried to execute two functions when the user clicks the button, but since the `shouldShow` constant is not a global variable it certainly doesn't work. Is there an elegant way to do this?